# Restful services config in J2EE not working

Tags: java, rest

I am working with j2EE project using servlets3 and jsp, and delivering application datas using restful services. So I am using following dependencies to get restful services in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Here, I have a class file called MyServices and it has following code, this way no need to code in the web.xml file for initiating restful servlet.

```
@ApplicationPath("f")
public class MyServices extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MyServices() {
        singletons.add(new MyAppServices());
        singletons.add(new MyCommonServices());
        singletons.add(new MyAddonServices());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Below, all 3 classes are pasted which initiated in MyServices.Java.

MyAppServices.Java has the path of /mobapi and it can be access by `localhost:8080/myapp/mobapi/..`

```
@Path(value = "/mobapi")
public class MyAppServices {

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/app/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(value = "param") String appId) {
        String token = documentDAO.mobileAppToken(appId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }
}
```

MyCommonServices.Java has the path of /, which means nothing and it can be access by `localhost:8080/myapp/..`

```
@Path(value = "/")
public class MyCommonServices {

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/app/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(value = "param") String appId) {
        String token = documentDAO.mobileAppToken(appId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }
}
```

MyAddonServices.Java has the path of /api, and it can be access by `localhost:8080/myapp/api/..`

```
@Path(value = "/api")
public class MyAddonServices {

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/app/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(value = "param") String appId) {
        String token = documentDAO.mobileAppToken(appId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }
}
```

Problem is I can access only `localhost:8080/myapp/app/6546` without issues.

But, I cant access other api's such as `localhost:8080/myapp/api/app/6546`  or `localhost:8080/myapp/mobapi/app/6546`

Is there anyother configuration is missing here, can some one help here please?

### Update

I am using Filter to handle requests to map like `localhost:8080/myApp/app/something` to  `localhost:8080/myApp/f/app/something` , as follows

MyFilter.java

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath();
            boolean isGet = "GET".equals(((HttpServletRequest) request)
                    .getMethod());
            String newPath = null;
            ((HttpServletRequest) request).getQueryString();

            try {
                ((HttpServletRequest) request).getQueryString();
                if (path.contains("api/")) {
                    newPath = "f"
                            + path
                            + "?"
                            + ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                                    .getQueryString();
                }else {
                    newPath = "f"
                            + path
                            + "?"
                            + ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                                    .getQueryString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                newPath = "f" + path;

            }
            request.getRequestDispatcher(newPath).forward(request, response);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

If I remove this filter I can access all the api's without issues such as, `localhost:8080/myApp/f/app/something` & localhost:8080/myApp/f/api/app/something`&localhost:8080/myApp/f/mobapi/app/something`

Can someone help in this filter?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { newPath = "f" + path; }`  you're not even logging any problems. *Start* with logging + throwing any exceptions, then try to do anything else.

Comment: What server are you running on?

Comment: @eis, that's not under exception even after I print the exception..

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way:

MyCommonServices.Java

```
@Path(value = "/app/{param}")
public class MyCommonServices {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(value = "param") String appId) {
        String token = documentDAO.mobileAppToken(appId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }
}
```

MyAppServices.Java

```
@Path(value = "/mobapi/app/{param}")
public class MyAppServices {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(value = "param") String appId) {
        String token = documentDAO.mobileAppToken(appId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }
}
```

MyAddonServices.Java

```
@Path(value = "/api/app/{param}")
public class MyAddonServices {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam(value = "param") String appId) {
        String token = documentDAO.mobileAppToken(appId);
        return Response.status(200).entity(token).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I also having other methods in those classes.

Comment: I think problem is with `@Path(value = "/")` MyCommonServices.Java can you change to `@Path(value = "/comm")` and check does other path works.

Comment: Can you check what response comes back when you try to access this url? To do this just press F12 on your browser and check network traffic. Also I'm wondering which j2ee server you are using and which version.

Comment: Sorry, The problem is with my filter. I updated my question. Can you look into that pls?

Comment: Hm i don't understand purpose of your filter :/

Answer (score 0):

What if you change `MyCommonServices` from `@Path(value = "/")` to `@Path(value = "/app")` and `@Path(value = "/app/{param}")` to `@Path(value = "/{param}")`?

Comment: Yes, changed it, but now it is also not working along with others.

Comment: Sorry, The problem is with my filter. I updated my question. Can you look into that pls?